# File reader library outputting null

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader

Because I'm too lazy to rewrite a file manager every time I make a project, I'm making a file IO library. When I run it, I get:

```
null
null
null
```

It finds how many lines are in the file, but puts them all as null. How can I fix this?

File manager:

```
package textfiles;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class KezelFile {

    private String path;
    BufferedReader buff;

    public KezelFile(String filePath) throws IOException {
        path = filePath;
        openFile();
    }

    public void openFile() throws IOException {
        FileReader read = new FileReader(path);
        buff = new BufferedReader(read);
    }

    public String[] toStringArray() throws IOException {

        int numberOfLines = readLines();
        String[] textData = new String[numberOfLines];

        int i;

        for (i=0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
        textData[i] = buff.readLine();

        }
        return textData;
    }

    int readLines() throws IOException {

        String lines;
        int noLines = 0;

        while ((lines = buff.readLine()) != null) {
            noLines++;
        }

        return noLines;
    }

    public void closeFile() throws IOException {
        buff.close();
    }

}
```

Main class:

```
package textfiles;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileData {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String filePath = "C:/test.txt";

        try {
            KezelFile file = new KezelFile(filePath);
            String[] aryLines = file.toStringArray();

            int i;
            for (i=0; i < aryLines.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(aryLines[i]);
            }
            file.closeFile();
        }

        catch (IOException error){
            System.out.println(error.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please don't reinvent the wheel - no one needs a square wheel. Especially not one with a slow puncture. Just use the [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) utility class.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have read all the lines, you can't read those lines again until you open the file again.  Just because the readLine() is called from a different method it doesn't "reset" the reader.

A better solution is to read the file just once.  I suggest you read the lines into a `List<String>` or even better process the file as you read it and you won't need the collection either.

BTW In Java 8 you can write

```
Files.lines(filename).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Perhaps it is time to try Java8 ;)

Comment: A better solution would be to use existing functionality - `Files.readAllLines` or `Files.lines`...

Comment: @BoristheSpider Assuming you have Java 8, yes. If you don't have Java 8, perhaps you should ;)